# Redirect www to the main domain without www with 301

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, redirect, passenger

I have a main domain "my_domain.com" and a few sub domains ("sub1.my_domain.com", "sub2.my_domain.com"...). It's possible to request a main domain as "my_domain.com" and "www.my_domain.com".

I need to redirect all the requests from "www.domain.com/.../any_url" to "domain.com" with the status 301. Or, preferably, all the requests from "www.domain.com/.../any_url" to "domain.com/.../any_url".

I've read some tutorials but didn't understand what's the standard and simplest way to do that. The web site is working on Rails, Passenger, Apache and Linux.

Here's what I have in `/etc/apache2`

```
root@my_user# ls -al 
total 88
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 Dec 26 19:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 111 root root  4096 Dec 23 03:27 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  8346 Feb  6  2012 apache2.conf
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec 26 19:09 conf.d
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1322 Feb  6  2012 envvars
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     0 Dec 26  2013 httpd.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 31063 Feb  6  2012 magic
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Apr 16  2014 mods-available
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec 30  2013 mods-enabled
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   750 Feb  6  2012 ports.conf
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Sep 22 13:22 sites-available
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Sep 22 13:22 sites-enabled
```

How can I do that? How do it by mod_rewrite, apache2.conf, /etc/apache2/sites-available/my_domain.com or using some other way? I'm confused.

update:

```
# ls -al /etc/apache2/sites-available
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 22 13:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Dec 26 19:22 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2716 May 16  2014 my_site-old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1499 Sep 22 13:22 my_site.my_domain123.com
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  950 Feb  6  2012 default
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7469 Feb  6  2012 default-ssl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1511 Dec 30  2013 puppetmaster
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2) to load mod_rewrite.

Use below rule where you have defined `ServerName www.domain.com`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName www.domain.com
  # Your existing customizations
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com$1 [R=301,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks. 1) what's the path of <path of mod_rewrite> 2) where do I have to write that `Use below rule where you have defined...` - in which file?

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2) to enable mod_rewrite. Look for `.conf` file under `sites-available`. Not sure if you have configurations for `www.domain.com` in `default.conf` or you have a separate `.conf` file for that. Review your `.conf` file under same location and use the rule in a conf file where it says `ServerName www.domain.com`

Comment: `Review your .conf file under same location ` - which conf file, in what location? I've updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: Check all conf files under `sites-available` if you don't know the correct file name. Try to find `ServerName www.domain.com` in each of these `.conf` files. It's difficult to tell which conf file need a change without looking at the content of a file.

Comment: As you can see, there're no conf files in sites-available directory at all.

Comment: Yes, check inside each directory..it could be `my_site-old` or `my_site.my_domain123.com`. There should be a conf file for your domain `www.domain.com`. I will take a look from my side and get back to you.

Comment: Or try this command `httpd -S` and it should give you list of enabled conf files with their virtual host name and location of conf file. Still looking for more info.

Comment: please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673694/redirect-from-the-domain-with-www-to-the-root-domain-working-but-not-completel

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:
edit the **application_controller.rb**, so you can apply the "filter" to all other controllers.

```
root@Ecommerce:/# nano /home/NAMEAPP/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
```

into the file, put this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_filter :redirect_subdomain

    def redirect_subdomain
      if request.host == 'www.dominio.cl'
        redirect_to 'http://dominio.cl' + request.fullpath
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: pero a mi no me gusta eso. lo siento.

Comment: Por qué no? algún tema de desempeño o simple gusto?. Saludos

Comment: Because doing that via apache is more natural, low level way. Yes, because of performance.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use [`rack-rewrite`](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) gem